# Doumo or dōmo / arigatou or arigatō

Tags: orthography, rōmaji

this may be a silly question. However, is there a difference between the following sentences (in terms of spelling):

1) Doumo arigatou gozaimashita. 
2) Dōmo arigatō gozaimashita.

Is one sentence more correct than the other? I know that they are used for giving thanks (past tense). But I am not sure if "doumo" or "domo" and "arigatou" or "arigatō" are more correct.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are seeing two different methods of [romanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese). 1) is in so-called [wāpuro rōmaji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C4%81puro_r%C5%8Dmaji), and 2) is in the [(modified) Hepburn system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization). Neither is more correct than the other; they are exactly the same if written as an ordinary kana-kanji Japanese sentence (どうも有難うございました), and they are pronounced the same. For details, please follow the links.

- [**Kunrei**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunrei-shiki_romanization): D**ô**mo arigat**ô** gozaima**si**ta.
- **(Modified) [Hepburn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization)**: D**ō**mo arigat**ō** gozaima**shi**ta.
- **"Passport" Hepburn**: D**o**mo arigat**o** gozaima**shi**ta.
- **[Wapuro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C4%81puro_r%C5%8Dmaji)**: D**ou**mo arigat**ou** gozaima**s(h)i**ta.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Naruto.